# Create New Profile without many clicks

Tags: profile, permission-sets

I wanted to create a new profile for user who only needed to have access on Account object to be able to see account records only without edit/create/delete permissions.

I found that to create a new profile with only account read access, I needed to clone an existing standard profile like Read Only and then manually go to edit permissions for all other objects to which it provides read only access and un-check all the other check boxes.

That seemed very time consuming and inefficient. Is there a short-cut/alternative method to create a new profile with only the read permission on one object quickly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a question asking for a direct answer to a Trailhead question - See discussion in Meta for more on this topic.

Comment: If you read till the end, i am asking for alternative way to quickly create a new profile without editing an existing / standard profile's so many checkboxes for different objects.

Comment: SF.SE doesn't wish to allow posts that resembles providing any kind of a direct solution to a Trailhead Challenge. Were your question restated such that it made no references to Trailhead and presented a scenario where you were looking for a more efficient solution to accomplishing a task, I'd have no issues with it. As currently phrased, it implicitly provides a potential solution to a Trailhead security challenge; something which is contrary to the objectives of SF.SE as discussed in [Meta](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1925/responding-to-trailhead-challenge-questions).